# How do I raise a number x to the power y in MARIE?

Tags: assembly, marie

I'm trying to create a MARIE program that raises a number (x) to a power (y) and provides an output. I have tried many alterations of the idea I have in mind but I am still facing errors. The code below is the closest I have gotten to solving this problem

```
INPUT
STORE X
STORE XNUM
INPUT
STORE Y

MULTIPLIERA,LOAD PROD
        ADD X
            STORE PROD
            LOAD XNUM
            SUBT ONE
            STORE XNUM
            SKIPCOND 400
            JUMP MULTIPLIERA
            JUMP NEWPRODUCT

NEWPRODUCT, LOAD X
            STORE XNUM
            LOAD PROD
            STORE X
            LOAD Y
            SUBT ONE
            STORE Y
            SKIPCOND 400
            JUMP MULTIPLIERA
            LOAD PROD

            OUTPUT
            HALT          

X, DEC 00
XNUM, DEC 00
Y, DEC 00
ONE, DEC 01
PROD, DEC 00

3^2 gives me a 36 and 1^3 gives me a 4
```

Comment: You have the right idea, a loop to do addition for multiplication, and a loop around that for power.  So, you just need to debug it.

Comment: Thanks! Trying that with the steps. Hopefully, I catch the error soon

Comment: See me [here](https://www.codementor.io/erikeidt) tomorrow if you need debugging help.

Comment: Yes sir! I will keep you posted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/ Start of the main program 
Input / Enter the exponent Store y
Subt One
Store Count

Input / Enter the Base
Store x
Store y
Jns Exp

/ Ending the main program
Load Ans 
Output 
End, Halt

Exp, Hex 0
Loop2, Load Count
    Skipcond 800
    JumpI Exp
    JnS Multiplier
    Load Ans
    Store x
    Load Count
    Subt One
    Store Counter
    Jump Loop2

/ Start of the subroutine Multiplier
Multiplier, Hex 0
    Load Zero
    Store Ans
    Loop, Load x
    Skipcond 800
    JumpI Multiplier
    Load Ans
    Add y
    Store Ans
    Load x
    Subt One
    Store x
    Jump Loop

/ Declaration
x, Dec 2
y, Dec 3
Zero, Dec 0
One, Dec 1 
Ans, Dec 0 
Count, Dec 0
```

This Should work Fine. Let me know if you have any problems regarding this.