# Marie JS to the power of

Tags: marie

I need to write a code for raising x to the power of y in Marie.js. That's what I have for now, however it spits out an error SyntaxError:L41 - Unknown label Loop.

```
Input 
Subt One
Store Count

Input 
Store x
Store y
Jns Exp


Load Wyn
Output 
End, Halt

Exp, Hex 0
Loop2, Load Count
    Skipcond 800
    JumpI Exp
    JnS Multi
    Load Wyn
    Store x
    Load Count
    Subt One
    Store Count
    Jump Loop2


Multi, Hex 0
    Load Zero
    Store Wyn
    Loop, Load x
    Skipcond 800
    JumpI Multi
    Load Wyn
    Add y
    Store Wyn
    Load x
    Subt One
    Store x
    Jump Loop


x, Dec 2
y, Dec 3
Zero, Dec 0
One, Dec 1 
Wyn, Dec 0 
Count, Dec 0
```

I understand the necessity for 2 loops, which execute y-1 times, however Im completely clueless what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I raise a number x to the power y in MARIE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58636468/how-do-i-raise-a-number-x-to-the-power-y-in-marie)

Comment: Not exactly, actually I used the code inside that post but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

You have to define a label before you can `Jump` to it; you have not defined the label `Loop`.  You *have* defined a label named `Loop2`.